# How do I make sure there are no duplicates in a mysql table?

Tags: sql, mysql

Suppose I have 2 fields: `first_name` and `last_name`.

It is ok to have first name duplicate, or last name duplicate, but, if both `first_name` and `last_name` are the same, do not insert! It's like 2 unique keys, linked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the table already exists, then you can alter it to add a composite unique key:

```
ALTER `table_name` ADD UNIQUE (`first_name`,`last_name`);
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a unique index on the combined fields:

```
ALTER `mytable` ADD UNIQUE (`first_name`,`last_name`);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by adding a unique constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE People
(
  First_Name VARCHAR(32),
  Last_Name VARCHAR(32),
  UNIQUE (First_name, Last_Name)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need is an index which combines both fields. Here's a sample table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `people` (
  `first` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `last` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `myIndex` (`first`,`last`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to add a unique index composed with these two fields to your table:

```
ALTER TABLE `your_table` ADD UNIQUE `uniq_name` ( `First_name` , `Last_name` )
```